# Insulating or air sealing around pipes in brick

Tags: insulation, sealing, masonry

I recently moved into a single story double masonry house and discovered a rather noticeable amount of cold air coming from around the dishwasher in the kitchen. I pulled out the machine and found that to run the drain pipe for the sink they had removed several of the interior layer of bricks.

I'm wondering what the best approach would be to insulate or seal around the pipes to cut down on the cold air coming in. I was thinking a spray foam insulation may be the best bet due to all the crevices, but wasn't sure if it expanding could cause issues with the pipes. Is that the route I should go or is there a better option?

[image: View of the entire space]

[image: Close up of the pipes]

Comment: For that top horizontal run, they've removed entire bricks. How far along  the wall does that go? The wall above is unsupported, so this is a little more complex than just drafts.

Comment: In the few jobs where we have removed more than 2 or 3 bricks we had to use angle iron to support the area with the web protruding at least 1/2 brick beyond the opening.+ I would at least spray foam the opening into the floor.

Comment: @PhilG good point. The opening is for a standard dishwasher, so the entire opening is 24 inches, and that top horizontal run is probably about 20 inches long. The lower run comes away from the wall immediately after going behind the cabinet so it's about 4-6 inches.